# How to create dynamic variable with selenium web driver in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium

I am developing a website testing project using C# with selenium. unfortunately, I am unable to create dynamic variable.

I want to create dynamic variable name  driver1 , driver2 , driver3... but it doesn't work.

```
private void MultipleThreading()
    {


        for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
        {

            int temp = 1;

            async void StartLogin()
            {

                    driver + temp = new ChromeDriver();

            }

            Thread th = new Thread(StartLogin);
            th.Start();
        }
    }
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Please edit your question and paste code instead of an image.

Comment: Even by looking at the image you've attached, I can't figure out what are you actually trying to do.

Comment: I just update the code. Could you please have a look?

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to add a number to the variable name. You can create any number of instances of the class.

If needed you can create a constructor for the class that takes the number to identify the driver:

(code not tested)

```
private void MultipleThreading()
    {
        List<ChromeDriver> drivers = new List<ChromeDriver>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver(i);
            drivers.Add(driver);
        }
        DoSomeThingWithDrivers(drivers);
    }
```